# Remove Multiple Shortcuts from HomeScreen

Tags: android, homescreen, shortcut

I am able to remove single shortcut from the code below. But if their are more than 1 shortcut on homescreen, it only removes single instance of the shortcut which was created or placed first.

```
        final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        shortcutIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packagename, classname));
        shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(
                "com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        intent.setClass(this, UninstallShortcutReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appName);
        intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packagename, classname));
         sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I have looked into launcher.db file but favorites table contains only single row of that application. Is their any field in that table which contains that mapping? How can I remove multiple shortcuts not single shortcut?

Comment: can you give me the reason for downvote ?

Comment: Well, if there are multiple shortcuts of the same type on the homescreen, I assume that they weren't created with intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);